# Logical comparison returning different result for same values

Tags: powershell, comparison, comparison-operators

I am absolutely lost as to what is happening here. I am simply comparing the values of two numbers and returning the result.
When I'm doing it in a custom property, the result is always False, even though the value is indeed greater.
When I take out just the comparison into its own line after the Select-Object operation, the correct result, True, is displayed.

Code examples:

```
$var = Get-BrokerDesktop -Filter {HostedMachineName -eq $machineName} | 
Select-Object -Property MachineName,
@{L="UptimeHours";E={(New-TimeSpan $_.LastHostingUpdateTime (Get-Date)).TotalHours}}, 
@{L='UptimeFormatted';E={'{0:%d} Days & {0:%h\:mm\:ss}' -f (New-TimeSpan $_.LastHostingUpdateTime (Get-Date))}},
@{L="ToRestart";E={[int]$_.UptimeHours -gt 24}},
RegistrationState     

[int]$var.UptimeHours -gt 24
```

For the record, UptimeHours is 87 in this case. 87.3 before the integer cast.

I am beyond confused how two identical logical comparisons can return different values.

Comment: You can only reference members that exist _on the input object_ - and the input object doesn't (yet) have an `UptimeHours` property, so the comparison is always `0 -gt 24` which is obviously false. Use 2 `Select-Object` statements back-to-back, or recreate the same TimeSpan value in both calculated property expressions

Comment: I don't have to do that, I can simply replace $_.UptimeHours with the expression I used to calculate the UptimeHours property, and now it works. Thank you for pointing it out, I assumed I could work with the new property value as long as it was defined and calcuilated earlier in the chain. Post your comment as an aswer so I can designate it as such if you wish!

Comment: As I said: "[...] or recreate the same TimeSpan value in both calculated property expressions" :)

Comment: And I need to learn to always read to the end of a sentence :)
Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `Select-Object` with calculate properties, the `$_` inside the property expression refers to *the current **input object*** - which **doesn't** have an `UptimeHours` property, otherwise you wouldn't need to create it in the first place :)

Either repeat the same time span calculation in both expressions:

```
...,@{L="ToRestart";E={[int](New-TimeSpan $_.LastHostingUpdateTime (Get-Date)).TotalHours -gt 24}},...
```

... or chain an extra `Select-Object` command onto the pipeline so you can select the last property based on the value of the ones first introduced with `Select-Object`:

```
... |Select-Object -Property MachineName,
    @{L="UptimeHours";E={(New-TimeSpan $_.LastHostingUpdateTime (Get-Date)).TotalHours}}, 
    @{L='UptimeFormatted';E={'{0:%d} Days & {0:%h\:mm\:ss}' -f (New-TimeSpan $_.LastHostingUpdateTime (Get-Date))}},
    RegistrationState | Select-Object -Property *,@{L="ToRestart";E={[int]$_.UptimeHours -gt 24}}
```